# � - Unknown character returned from SQL Server (PHP)

Tags: php, sql-server

When querying a database table in my PHP script, an unknown character is returned: �

So, I investigated the data in the table and came across the following; the unknown characters are actually “ ” - a different kind of double quote (in comparison to " "). These have a different html code in comparison to the regular double quotes.

`&#8220; = “ - &#8220; = ” - &#34; = "`

I attempted to just echo the different quotes in my PHP script and strangely it worked, and viewing the data in SQL Management Studio - the quotes appear fine.

How can I fix this so it displays the quotes correctly?

Comment: html_entity_decode(); use this

Comment: i think you want to set utf8_encode()

Comment: check your db is it capable to store utf8 characters?

Comment: do you want to ignore this character? �

Comment: utf8_encode gets rid of the unknown characters. However I would like the characters to be replaced to the actual double quotes

Comment: this will ignore this char:  htmlentities(@iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $string));

Comment: @devpro Not sure if you saw my last comment buy I don't want it to ignore the character. I want it to replace the unknown character to the actual character it is meant to be

Comment: and echo  str_replace("�",'"',$string); this will replace with double quote

Comment: if actual is only double quote than use str_replace, yes, i didnt check yur last comment sorry.

Comment: I mean it works, but I can't be sure for certain that all unknown characters will be the double quotes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99691/discussion-between-devpro-and-callum-luke-vernon).